# Java Transaction: how to stop program after rollback?

Tags: java, transactions, execution, rollback

I have the following code that carries out database operations within a `transaction`:

```
  try {
                //start transaction
                repository.startTransaction();

               //carry out deletion logic
                repository.deletedata()

                //commit all 3 transactions
                 repository.commitTransaction();

      }catch (Exception e) {    
                 repository.rollback();
            }
```

Currently if there is an `error` when running, the application still **continues running**. However, I would like the execution of the program to **stop** after the data has been rolled back.

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to terminate the execution you should use your own business-level exception.

Secondly, statement `repository.rollback();` may fail, too. Just an idea.

My approach would be:

```
class MyApp {
    public static final main(){
        new MyApp().run();
    }

    private void run(){
        MyRepositoryProcessor proc = new MyRepositoryProcessor();

        try {
            // Some loop here maybe...
            proc.deleteFromRepo();
        } catch (MyDatabaseCommunicationException ex) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

class MyRepositoryProcessor {
    public void deleteFromRepo() throws MyDatabaseCommunicationException {
        try {
            //start transaction
            repository.startTransaction();

            //carry out deletion logic
            repository.deletedata()

            //commit all 3 operations
            repository.commitTransaction();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                repository.rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex){
                // Database connection failed completely, could not even do a rollback.
            }
            throw new MyDatabaseCommunicationException("Deletion failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although how does this stop the program execution?

Comment: It stops the control flow execution up to the point you catch the exception. If you want to completely exit the program you should definitely do it higher then on database level. You could then use System.exit() with some appropriate code.

Comment: Ok, so add System.exit() after the database rollback?

Comment: I updated the answer to promote my idea better. So, yes, System.exit() exits the application. And no, you should not call it directly after a rollback. It should be called from a higher level.

Comment: Why should it be called at a higher level?

Comment: If I would be implementing some functionality that internally uses `deleteFromRepo()` I definitely want to have a possibility to decide what to do if the `DELETE` fails. I may fix the data, write to log, send an email or whatever. That's why I will be expecting a meaningful exception instead of "kill application now!" :)

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(0) ?

You can find some documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: Thanks, does this just stop the program from executing any other code?